# a macro that creates object in clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm trying to create a macro that dynamically creates java objects in Clojure with **annotations**.

I've been trying both `proxy` and `reify` with no success facing `CompilerException`.

Here is as far as got:

#### Proxy

fist attempt was to create an object without a macro:

```
(.toString 
  (proxy [java.lang.Object] [] 
    (toString [] (str "proxyToString"))))
```

which results to  : `=> "proxyToString"`

then i tried to wrap it with a macro and pass the `object` as parameter:

```
(defmacro create-obj-with-proxy [klass]
  `(proxy [~klass] [] (toString [] (str "proxyToString"))))
```

which results to : `=> #'oppose/create-obj-with-proxy`

and i can expand or evaluate it

```
(macroexpand (create-obj-with-proxy java.lang.Object))
(.toString (create-obj-with-proxy java.lang.Object))
```

it works with reify as well.

```
(defmacro create-obj-with-reify [klass]
  `(reify ~klass
              (toString [this] "reifyToString")))

(macroexpand (create-obj-with-reify java.lang.Object)) 
(.toString (create-obj-with-proxy java.lang.Object)
```

But if i associate the class name to a variable, i get exceptions

```
(def give-me-class java.lang.Object)
(def give-me-class-fn [] java.lang.Object)
(.toString (create-obj-with-proxy give-me-class))
(.toString (create-obj-with-proxy (give-me-class-fn)))


(.toString (create-obj-with-proxy give-me-class))
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Var cannot be cast to java.lang.Class, compiling:

(.toString (create-obj-with-proxy (give-me-class-fn)))
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol, compiling:
```

Any suggestions ?

Edit: thanks to @Michiel Borkent fixed the object creation issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but need to remove the splicing operator:

```
(defmacro create-obj-with-proxy [klass]
  `(proxy [~klass] [] (toString [] (str "proxyToString"))))
```

Then

```
(create-obj-with-proxy java.lang.Object)
```

will return

```
#object[dre.compress.proxy$java.lang.Object$ff19274a 0x6c221bc8 "proxyToString"]
```

You're passing in a symbol argument. With unquote-splice you're trying to treat that as a sequence, which won't work, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, it works! if I extract java.lang.Object as a function or def I get null pointer exception :/  `(def give-me-class java.lang.Object)
(def give-me-class-fn [] java.lang.Object)
(.toString (create-obj-with-proxy give-me-class))
(.toString (create-obj-with-proxy (give-me-class-fn)))`

Comment: When you evaluate `(create-obj-with-proxy foo)` the symbol foo has to evaluate to a class. `give-me-class` is not a symbol for a class, that's why the above doesn't work. So you'll get an error like  java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Var cannot be cast to java.lang.Class.

Comment: Is there a way to make the result a class ? i tried (class give-me-class)

Comment: Macros do not evaluate their arguments first, like functions do. Look at the macro-expansion of what you are trying to write and then it should be clear I hope.

Comment: I've tried `(defmacro create-obj-with-proxy [klass] `(proxy [~(class klass)] [] (toString [] (str "proxyToString"))))` and `(defmacro create-obj-with-proxy [klass]
  `(proxy [~(class ~klass)] [] (toString [] (str "proxyToString"))))` both resulted in `CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol,`

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to create `HelloWorldImpl` class using clojure on apache CXF  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with this nor the Java annotations that go with it, but it might be worth asking this in new SO question and be as specific as you can be, before it turns into a general question about macros.